# After authentication,page redirects back to login page

Tags: asp.net, authentication, authorization

I have a simple login page as below:

```
   protected void btnLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormsAuthentication.Initialize();

    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IS"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
      {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Roles from tblRegisteredUsers where Email=@Email and Password=@Password",con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if(rdr.Read())
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
                txtEmail.Text,
                DateTime.Now,
                DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
                true,
                rdr.GetString(0),
                FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
            string hash = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,hash);
            if(ticket.IsPersistent) cookie.Expires=ticket.Expiration;
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

            string returnUrl = Request.QueryString["returnUrl"];
            if(returnUrl==null) returnUrl="/";
            Response.Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Invalid Email/Password.Please try again.";
        }
        rdr.Close();
    }
}
```

I have used folder level roles authentication with each folder having its own web.config file.I am sure that the user gets authenticated successfully because the see the username in loginName.This is definitely a redirection issue.What can i do to redirect the users to my Homepage after successful login?

Is anybody still helping me on this?

Comment: What value is passed in for the `returnUrl` request parameter?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen - I dont see anything that specifies the returnUrl request parameter.You must be talking about the querystring request right? So,where do i assign that?

Comment: You're getting the `returnUrl` request parameter here: `string returnUrl = Request.QueryString["returnUrl"];`

Comment: I understand that.But how do i make out what the value is each time a user logs in?

Comment: Well, for starters, add a debug statement to see what the actual value is that you're receiving. If it's some form of login URL, then that's the cause of your issue right there.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen - It comes out as null

Comment: Since returnurl is null you are  being redirected to ('/') which is the homepage (i.e the login page). Just make sure "returnurl" is not blank if it is then redirect to the page you want like returnUrl = '/pagename'.

Answer (score 0):

just a suggestion. you may redirect to homepage or if required then create a global variable and maintain the last visited page url in it. hope it helps

Comment: have you tried static URL in Response.Redirect or in your 'returnUrl' ?

Answer (score 0):

**string returnUrl = Request.QueryString["returnUrl"];**

I think your query string fetch null value thats why it statifises the IF condition and take the return URL as '/' so it redirects to current page.

Put a debug point near the highlighted portion and see what value you are getting for return url

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
string returnUrl = Request.QueryString["returnUrl"];
        if(returnUrl==null) returnUrl="/";
        Response.Redirect(returnUrl);
```

just write

```
 Response.Redirect(<"your url for the homepage">);
```

Eg

For MVC application it will be `Response.Redirect("/home/index");`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to redirect to another page like this:

```
Response.Redirect("myhomepage.aspx");
```

you need to provide your page name with **.aspx** extension at the end unlike that in MVC where you needed to provide the URL.